# Are there any solutions available which integrate emacs and TFS?

Tags: emacs, tfs

Googling emacs and tfs the first few results seemed violent. I'm wondering has anyone had any luck using emacs in an environment where tfs was used? Are there any packages readily available which will allow me to use emacs with tfs without doing a heavy amount of customization on my part? If it's of any consequence my operating system is winxp.

Comment: I think the answer is NO, there is no tfs plugin for the version control capability in emacs.  I'd be willing to investigate writing it, though.  I am completely unfamiliar with the emacs vc.el module, where all the version control modules fit in.  I'll have to look.

Comment: what commands would you want?  tf checkout/edit, checkin, history, diff, undo, properties?

Comment: tf (add|checkin|checkout|delete|get|rename|shelve|undo) seem reasonable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's [a first cut.](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/EmacsTfs.aspx)
And [the link to emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MSTFS).

Comment: Dave, don't think I did this for you.  I didn't.  I did it for me.  You just happened to be here at the right moment.  ;)